Doubt on graph of indefinite integration starting from 0 instead of $-\infty$
The graph of integration of a function show us the area under the function.
If we specify the range of integration we plot the graph between the range.
So if we just use indefinite integration we should plot the graph from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ right?
But why are we plotting the graph from 0 on the axis instead of $-\infty$ ?
Thanks for explaining in advance.

The indefinite integral of a function is not a function, so you can't even begin to think about graphing it. It is a family of functions, differing by the various values of the "constant of integration", which determines (or is determined by) where you put the lower limit of the corresponding definite integral.

So indefinite integration is not a function?

$\int x,dx=(1/2)x^2+C$. $\int_a^xt,dt=(1/2)x^2-(1/2)a^2$. You better not take $a=-\infty$ for this one.

True...If we take indefinite then we can't even do the calculation

Indefinite integration is an operation. But, to repeat myself, "The indefinite integral of a function is not a function."

Ok thanks for the idea
